# objective C Warning that I Don't Understand

Tags: objective-c

Can anyone explain to me why I get these warnings:

```
Conflicting parameter types in implementation of 'setCardsSelected': 'NSMutableArray *' vs 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long')
Conflicting return type in implementatin of 'setCardsSelected': 'void' vs 'NSMutableArray *'
```

I'm just trying to pass in an `NSUInteger` to a function. Why does this not work? Is my method declaration wrong? Thanks!

```
- (NSMutableArray *) setCardsSelected:(NSUInteger) index
{
    if (!_cardsSelected) _cardsSelected = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    return _cardsSelected;
}
```

Comment: Is that really the method implementation? Why is the parameter ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*edit*:

the problem is you have defined the property `cardsSelected` and the associated setter is `setCardsSelected:` (which is of course `-(void)setCardsSelected:(NSMutableArray*)array`).

You will have to change your method name (what abut `selectCards:`?) or declare your property with a different setter, like this:

`@property ( nonatomic, strong, setter=setterSelector: ) NSMutableArray * cardsSelected`

I think renaming your method is preferable.

---

Yes, your method declaration is wrong.

I guess you are overriding a method `setCardsSelected:` in a subclass; in the superclass (or adopted protocol) I guess it's `-(void)setCardsSelected:(NSMutableArray*)array`

Comment: No, I'm not overriding anything. I'm intending to return a pointer to an NSMutableArray. I'm passing in the index integer because I intend to do something with it before I return the array (that code isn't written yet). When I remove the ':(NSUInteger) index' part, the warning goes away.

Comment: This is a private method, so I have no corresponding method declaration in my header file.

Comment: I know that `index` is an already-defined in `C` sometimes... and I see that you're not actually using `index` in your code. What if you change the variable name? Just guessing now.

Comment: I changed it to 'idx', but same result. Weird. At least I'm not missing something totally obvious. Thanks for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Can you paste your entire file somewhere?

Comment: Thanks. I just figured that out, too. Live and learn... I appreciate all of your help!

Comment: I tried your code myself and that's when I saw the problem :)